# cloud code in parse.com doesn't work to all data

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I just start learning how to modify my database in [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com). I'm using `cloud code` in my mac.

In my database, I got around 150 data, with class `openhour` and `closehour`. Unfortunately, it was written in `string`. It's structure is like this `12:30`.

I want to convert all of it from `string` to `number`, and store it in class `openHour` and `closeHour`. For an example, I will change `12:30` as `string`, to `12.5` as `number`.

I've wrote this code, deploy it, and execute it using terminal in mac. It seems succeeded since I can see some of my data in class `openHour` and `closeHour` are being filled.

My problem is, there are several data that are still empty. Can someone show me why this is happening? did I miss something?

```
var _ = require('underscore.js');
Parse.Cloud.define("openclose", function(request, response) {
               Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
               var query = new Parse.Query("Places");
               query.limit = 1000;
               query.find().then(function(results) {
                                 _.each(results, function(result) {
                                        var openString = result.get("openhour");
                                        var openHourString = openString.slice(0,2);
                                        var openHour = Number(openHourString);

                                        var openMinuteString = openString.slice(3);
                                        var openMinute = Number(openMinuteString);

                                        result.set("openHour", openMinute/60 + openHour);

                                        var closeString = result.get("closehour");
                                        var closeHourString = closeString.slice(0,2);
                                        var closeHour = Number(closeHourString);

                                        var closeMinuteString = closeString.slice(3);
                                        var closeMinute = Number(closeMinuteString);

                                        result.set("closeHour", closeMinute/60 + closeHour);
                                        });
                                 return Parse.Object.saveAll(results);
                                 }).then(function(results) {
                                         response.success(results);
                                         }, function(error) {
                                         response.error(error);
                                         });
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "return" before before the query.find()

```
return query.find().then(function(results) {
```

Also - I assume you have < 1,000 rows of data? Otherwise, you will need to make this recursive because of the max query limit.

Comment: as I mentioned above, my data is around 150. I haven't tried your code, but after waiting a while, and try to execute the code again, it works. Do you know why?

Comment: So did it just start working all of a sudden? Does it work consistently now or are you still having problems? It could have been an error on Parse's side if that is the case.